# Is Mono framework or mono runtime part of the Xamarin IOS ipa package?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Basically, my question is if Xamarin IOS is statically compiled or compiled ahead of time (AOT), why do we need Mono Runtime within ipa?

May be I do not understand how does xamarin ios work in the ios devices?

Please can anybody shed some light?

Answer (score 2):

> When you compile any Xamarin platform application, the Mono C# (or F#)
>   compiler will run and will compile your C# and F# code into Microsoft
>   Intermediate Language (MSIL). If you are running a Xamarin.Android, a
>   Xamarin.Mac application, or even a Xamarin.iOS application on the
>   simulator, the .NET Common Language Runtime (CLR) compiles the MSIL
>   using a Just in Time (JIT) compiler. At runtime this is compiled into
>   a native code, which can run on the correct architecture for your
>   application.
>
> However, there is a security restriction on iOS, set by Apple, which
>   disallows the execution of dynamically generated code on a device. To
>   ensure that we adhere to these safety protocols, Xamarin.iOS instead
>   uses an Ahead of Time (AOT) compiler to compile the managed code. This
>   produces a native iOS binary, optionally optimized with LLVM for
>   devices, that can be deployed on Apple’s ARM-based processor.

[iOS App Architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en/xamarin/ios/internals/architecture) this link may be useful to you for more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the link mate. I already saw it. However, I'm still not clear why do we need Mono Runtime when everything is compiled to native instructions that the IOS device understands.

Comment: even this creates a confusion
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/internals/architecture-images/ios-arch.png#lightbox
Does ipa contains mono runtime or not?

Answer (score 2):

> why do we need Mono Runtime within ipa?

The native ARM code that is generated by Xamarin.iOS (`mtouch`) AOT process depends upon the Mono runtime as the AOT process is not a transcoding compiler.

This dependency is mainly for the garbage collector but it also provides the runtime interface from the low level .Net/Mono framework calls to the iOS|tvOS|watchOS operating system.

Comment: Please can you elaborate ".Net/Mono framework calls to the IOS/tvOS" because when you convert to native code (instructions), I believe there is nothing like ".Net/Mono" , it just all machine code??

Comment: @ZammyPage Not sure I understand your question, Mono provides the runtime interface to the operating system, yes the AOT process created machine code, but it does not always directly call a native OS function, but a native Mono provided one, in term Mono processes that request and then makes native OS calls.

Comment: Thanks buddy. I think that is what I was missing. I thought the machine code created directly calls the native OS function. it makes sense now. Please can you put that details in the answer so that I can mark your response as answer. Thanks again.